# Swift: Dictionary Key contain the value still it's error nil

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, dictionary, null

when I try to print the value of the dictionary key `fromdate` it's showing the Error even it's contain the value with that particular key.

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an
>   Optional value

This is code for the saving the value in the Dictionary.

```
 func saveRecentSearch()  {
        var dictSearch = [String:Any]()

        if let onJourney = Global.onWordJ {
            dictSearch["From"] = onJourney.source?.CM_CityName
            dictSearch["Fromid"] = onJourney.source?.CM_CityID
            dictSearch["To"] = onJourney.destination?.CM_CityName
            dictSearch["Toid"] = onJourney.destination?.CM_CityID
            let date = onJourney.journeyDate
            let formatter = DateFormatter()
            formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
            let myString = formatter.string(from: date!)
            let yourDate: Date? = formatter.date(from: myString)
            formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"
            let updatedString = formatter.string(from: yourDate!)
            print(updatedString)
            dictSearch["fromdate"] = updatedString
        }
```

The key `fromdate` already save that date. Check the image

[image]

But when I try to retrieve that data it's found nil in "fromdate" key. Here is code.

```
var arrSearch = [[String:Any]]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        if let arr = UserDefault["Search"] {
            arrSearch.append(contentsOf: (arr as! [[String:Any]]))
        } 
             self.tblSearch.reloadData()
    }
```

> tableView Method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCell") as! RecentCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let dict = arrSearch[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblFrom.text = (dict["From"] as! String)
        cell.lblTo.text = (dict["To"] as! String)
        let strDate = (dict["fromdate"])
        cell.lblDate.text = (strDate as! String) //This line showing Error
        return cell
    }
```

What is the wrong with code? I got all the value rest the `fromdate` key value.

Comment: How? I already assign the value to `lblDate`

Comment: Your two methods probably not using the same dictionary.

Comment: If you sure that this field will surely return value then try this : `let strDate = (dict["fromdate"]!)`

Comment: try that still same error. @Denis

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia, then check your `lblDate` Outlet is properly connected inside cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because `dictSearch` expects `Any` as a variable but you’re passing `String` therefore, it crashes:

Maybe if all the variables are Strings, change it to:

```
var dictSearch = [String:String]()
```

If not, you’ll need to cast the date as any not string

This is not recommended, but try this:

```
guard let strDate = dict["fromdate"] as? String else { 
    print("error")
    return
} 
yourlabel.text = strDate
```

Comment: its print Error every time.

Comment: @KrunalNagvadia, gotcha, it is because `fromDate` cannot be casted as String hence the compiler fails, best to use` [String:String]` on the dictionary

Answer (score 1):

You should get value from dictionary by casting.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RecentCell") as! RecentCell
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        let dict = arrSearch[indexPath.row]
        cell.lblFrom.text = (dict["From"] as! String)
        cell.lblTo.text = (dict["To"] as! String)
        if let strDate = (dict["fromdate"] as? String)
        {
           cell.lblDate.text = strDate
         }

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: it's directly jump to the outside of the if Parts.

Comment: its mean your data not store in dictionary as a string

Comment: Just print whole dict which is set in cell and see value is available for "fromdate" key